# How to bind multiple select components to a single Angular 6+ reactive forms without emitting duplicate changes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I need to bind multiple input components to a single angular reactive form, but I have two problems:

- out of the box only the form where the user input happens is updated
- if I use [(ngModel)] it works but it also triggers a second change event

How can I keep two select components in sync with the data model without triggering a 2nd event?

**template**

```
<select [(ngModel="foo")] [formControl]="bar">
   <option *ngFor="let foo in foos" [value]="foo.value"> {{foo.name}}</option>
</select>
<select [(ngModel="foo")] [formControl]="bar">
   <option *ngFor="let foo in foos" [value]="foo.value"> {{foo.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**component**

```
foo = '';
bar: FormControl; 
...
formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(data => ...//this is called two times)
```

Comment: that should be `[(ngModel)]="foo"` and `bar.valueChanges...`, typo?

Comment: btw, what is the purpose of using both `ngModel` and `formControl` directives at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually patching the events while omitting an event does propagates the new value to every bound element in the template.

```
bar.valueChanges.subscribe(data => bar.patchValue(data , { emitEvent: false }))
```